# Why is my passport auth code giving a reference letter despite following the documentation?

Tags: passport-local-mongoose

I've used this code before to authenticate a secrets type of application and for some reason this time it isn't working.. all node package modules are install and this error pops up on display:

```
ReferenceError: respond is not defined
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\app.js:102:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:343:9)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\passport\lib\strategies\session.js:69:12
    at pass (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:337:31)
    at deserialized (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:349:7)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ayanda Gatsha Full Stack JS Web Developer\Ayandas Digital School For Digital Developers\SRS Saver App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:5074:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

---

```
// jshint esversion:6
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");

const session = require("express-session");

const script = require(__dirname + "/lib/script.js");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

moment = require("moment"); // require

// Load the full build.
const _ = require("lodash");

// const lowerCase = require('lodash.lowercase');

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  }),
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/userDB";
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
// const secret = "mysecret";

// userSchema.plugin(encrypt, {secret: process.env.SECRET, encryptedFields:["password"]});

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());

passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("home");
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  User.register(
    { username: req.body.username },
    req.body.password,
    function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/");
      } else {
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
          res.redirect("/dashboard");
        });
      }
    },
  );
});

app.get("/dashboard", function (req, res) {
  respond.render("dashboard", { packageData: momentData });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Passport at all, or any external documentation.

You have a simple typo.

```
app.get("/dashboard", function (req, res) {
  respond.render("dashboard", { packageData: momentData });
});
```

should be

```
app.get("/dashboard", function (req, res) {
  res.render("dashboard", { packageData: momentData });
});
```

since there is no `respond` variable.